# bash/unix toolchain binary stream processing/slicing

Tags: bash, unix, binary-data

I have a binary stream on standard input, it's in a fixed size format, a continuos stream of packets, each packet has a header with length X and a body with length Y.

So if X=2 Y=6 then it's something like `00abcdef01ghijkl02mnopqr03stuvwx`, but it's binary and both the header and data can contain *any* "characters" (including '\0' and newline), the example is just for readability.

I want to get rid of the header data so the output looks like this: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx`.

Are there any commands in the unix toolchain that allow me to do this? And in general are there any tools for handling binary data? The only tool I could think of is `od`/`hexdump` but how do you convert the result back to binary?

Comment: Are these network packets? What about tcpdump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `xxd` which goes to and from a hexdump.

```
xxd -c 123 -ps
```

will output your stream with 123 bytes per line.  To reverse use

```
xxd -r -p
```

You should now be able to put this together with `cut` to drop characters since you can do something like

```
cut -c 3-
```

to get all characters from 3 to the end of a line.  Do not forget to use a number of characters equal to 2X to account for two hex characters per byte.

So something along the lines of

```
xxd -c X+Y -ps | cut -c 2X+1- | xxd -r -p
```

where `X+Y` and `2X+1` are replaced with actual numerical values.  You'll need to put your datastream somewhere appropriate in to the above command.

Comment: so the idea was ok.. `xxd`, never heard about it. Thanks! note: the cut is from `2X+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is a pretty standard unix tool. Pipe it to perl. If its fixed length byte aligned a simple substr operation should work. Here is a perl sample that should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $buf;
my $len = 8;
my $off = 2;
while(sysread(STDIN,$buf,$len) != 0 ){
  print substr($buf,$off);
}

exit 0;
```

Comment: True, but at least its configurable ;)

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner, I'd write:

```
perl -00 -ne 'chomp; while (/(?:..)(......)/sg) {print $1}'
```

example:

```
echo '00abcdef01ghijkl02mnopqr03stuvw
00abcdef01ghi
kl02mnopqr' | perl -00 -ne 'chomp; while (/(?:..)(......)/sg) {print $1}' | od -c
```

produces

```
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p
0000020   q   r   s   t   u   v   w  \n   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
0000040   i  \n   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r
0000052
```

Comment: eats leading newlines `echo -e "\n00abcdef01.."`. any idea?

Comment: @yi_H, yeah, go with bot403's ["sysread" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080887/bash-unix-toolchain-binary-stream-processing-slicing/7081227#7081227).

Answer (score 0):

There's also `bbe - binary block editor`, which is kind of binary `sed` for handling binary data the Unix way.

http://bbe-.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

The binary stream editor is a tool written in java for handling streams.
It can be used from java as well as command line.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/bistreameditor/

DISCLAIMER : i am the author of this tool.

Unlike new-line based tools like sed, it allows custom traversing and data-storage via the traversal and buffer. Binary data can be treated as one byte chars and string operations/matches allowed. It can write to multiple outputs and use different encodings. Because of this flexibility, currently the command line has a lot of parameters, which needs to be simplified.

The bse.zip file should be downloaded and used.
For the above example, we would simply need to do a substr(2) on the input of len 8. The full command line is

```
java -classpath "./bin:$CMN_LIB_PATH/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$CMN_LIB_PATH/commons-io-2.1.jar:$CMN_LIB_PATH/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar:$CMN_LIB_PATH/commons-lang3-3.1.jar" 
-Dinputsrc=file:/fullpathtofile|URL|System.in 
-Dtraverser=org.milunsagle.io.streameditor.FixedLengthTraverser 
-Dtraversercons=size -Dtraverserconsarg0=8 
-Dbuffer=org.milunsagle.io.streameditor.CircularBuffer 
-Dbuffercons=size -Dbufferconsarg0=8 
-Dcommands='PRN V $$__INPUT.substring(2)' 
org.milunsagle.io.streameditor.BinaryStreamEditorInvoker
```